# VSCode から Python のコードが実行できない

Tags: python, macos, vscode

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]Google Colabだと動くコードがVSCodeだと`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`と表示されうまく動きません。

簡単なコード、例えば `print("hello")`を実行すると `hello` が出力されますが、
以下のようなコードを実行するとエラーが出ます。

プログラミング自体初めてなので右も左もよくわかりませんが、ご教授よろしくお願いします。

追記
画像をアップロードしました。
すみません。oriri様の質問がよくわからなかったのでVScodeの画面をアップしました。
コードを入力し、shift+enterで実行しました。
これでoriri様の答えが出ているといいのですが。

**エラーメッセージ：**

```
>>> /Users/ユーザー名/miniforge3/bin/python /Users/ユーザー名/python/bmi
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    /Users/ユーザー名/miniforge3/bin/python /Users/ユーザー名/python/bmi
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

**コード：**

```py
lists = ["ウォーキングデッド", "アントラージュ"]
for list in lists:
  print(list)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: VS Codeでどのようにして実行したのでしょう？ カレントファイルの実行だけでも Jupyterでのインタラクティブウィンドウで実行とか, Pythonでの統合ターミナルで実行とか(もしかして他にも？)種類があるので。colabと同様にするのならコマンドパレットから create: new jupyter notebook で開いてコード入力し実行すると良いでしょう

Comment: Pythonインタープリターは, 最初のスクリーンショットでは右下に出ていてそれが使われている。インタープリター選択のスクリーンショットでは, 最新版と思しきものと condaの miniforgeと, homebrewなどが出てる。ので, 利用したいもの選べばいいでしょう (分からなければ「おすすめ」選ぶとか)

Comment: インタープリターにお勧めを選びました。すると、ターミナルでPythonファイルを実行するを選択したらprint("helloworld")すら動かなくなってしましました。エラーがSyntaxError: invalid syntaxと出ています。しかし、Shift＋Enterだと問題なく動くのです。低レベルな事で申し訳ないのですがもう少し助力をお願いします。

Comment: まず現在の状況を正しく質問に書き加えてください。
そもそも 拡張子は変更したのかどうか `.py` なのか `.ipynb`なのか。
動かそうとしてる Pythonスクリプトは上記のままなのか。
統合ターミナルで実行するのなら …
最初どのような状態になってて, 何を選んだら, どのようにメッセージが出たかなど (`SyntaxError'と出てた付近にはどの部分がエラーか出てたはず)。

ヘルプセンターには[質問にあたって](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) などの項目あるので
目を通したほうがよいでしょう。

Comment: project.pyという名前にしたのでこれで拡張子は問題ないでしょうか。新しくスクリーンショットを追加しました。あれこれいじっていたら急に動かなくなってしまい、シンプルなコードならと思ってスクリーンショットの内容のコードを打ってみました。この場面でターミナルでpythonファイルを実行するを選んだところ、画像のエラーが出ました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> で実行したということは, 標準的なキーボード・ショートカットの`"python.execSelectionInTerminal"` (Pythonターミナルで選択範囲/行を実行する) を行ったと思われます。

カーソルをどこかの行に置いてただろうけど不明で, 何がどうエラーになったかは分からない

---

Google Colab や [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) と同じように**セル単位**で動かしたいのであれば

- VS Codeのコマンドパレット <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> から `Create: New Jupyter Notebook` を選び, プログラムを入力 (頭文字を SPC区切りで<kbd>c n j n</kbd>… などタイプしていくと選ぶの容易 <kbd>c j n</kbd>とかでも大丈夫)
- あるいは Colabのコマンドパレットから該当する Notebookを「.ipynbをダウンロード」でローカルに取得, それを VS Codeで開く
- あとは Colab同様の操作で実行可能 (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> もしくは「セルの実行」を行う)

あるいは (セルではなく) 単独の Pythonスクリプトとして実行するなら

- ["shebang" 行](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/interpreter.html?highlight=shebang#the-interpreter-and-its-environment) 付けるか, 拡張子の [.py を付ける](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=.py) (あるいはその両方)
- (セルの集合でない) Pythonスクリプトファイルを VS Codeで実行する場合は, 右クリックからの「ターミナルで Pythonファイルを実行」 (あるいは VS Codeのコマンドパレットから当該機能を選択)

… の手順になるでしょう
(Interactive Window の説明は蛇足かもなので割愛)

---

【追記】

質問にあるスクリーンショットからは, 拡張子のないスクリプトに読み取れます。
VS Codeであれば [Language Mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview)選択で, その間は Pythonスクリプトとして扱うことが可能。

しかし VS Codeから離れると, OSにとってそれが何のファイルかわからない。ので普通は以下の手段で指定

- ファイル名拡張子を付ける … ファイル名見ただけで分かる
- "shebang" 行を付ける … `$ file -i FILENAME` もしくは `$ xdg-mime query filetype FILENAME` で分かる
- OS側で用意されてる(かもしれない)拡張属性に指定する
- (あるいはその他)

(OSにとっても, スクリプト作成者本人にとっても(数カ月後には忘れてるかもなので) そのような情報は大切)

---

#### 【追記】project.py 実行に関して

Pythonインタプリターを使うには以下の方法があります

- コマンドラインで次のように指定する方法 (https://docs.python.org/ja/3/using/cmdline.html)

  ```bash
  $ python myscript.py   # スクリプトファイル名は適したものを指定
  ```
- [対話モード(Interactive Mode)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode) を利用する方法

docs.python.org には [Python チュートリアル](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/) があるので使い方見ておいたほうがよいでしょう

VS Codeでも, Python動かすために知っておいたほうがよいことがいくつかあり, この回答の最初の方に記したこともそのうちのひとつ。

(たとえば <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> で動いたとか動かないとかだけど, それは [Language Mode, 言語モード](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview) によって機能(割り当てが)異なるものだし, [Integrated Terminal, 統合ターミナル](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) での操作時も機能が異なる)

「<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> 押したら動くはず」
というのではなく, なるべく状況を把握して利用するのがよいでしょう

---

対話モードのプロンプトが行頭に表示され入力待ちになっているのなら

```py
>>>
```

それはたぶん, 「カーソルの置いてある行を実行する」で実行したまま放置してるのかも
その状態でターミナルのコマンド入力しても, Pythonスクリプトとして認識しようとしエラーに
なので いったん抜けて終了してください (macOS でも <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> かな？)

Comment: oriri様コメントありがとうございます。ご指摘の右クリックからの「ターミナルで Pythonファイルを実行」 で動かなかったコードも動くようになりました。丁寧な説明どうもありがとうございました。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。見知らぬキーワードが多かったので調べながら少しずつ勉強させていただいています。Create: New Jupyter Notebookでcolabのように動かすことができました。このモードでコードを打つ上で欠点などはありますか？それと、コードを選択し、pythonターミナルで選択範囲/行を実行するを選択したらコードが動きました。ただ、相変わらずターミナルでpythonファイルを実行するでは動きません。

Answer (score 0):

もしかして、pythonを起動して
「/Users/ユーザー名/miniforge3/bin/python /Users/ユーザー名/python/bmi」
を入力実行しているのではないですか？

```
% python

Python 3.10.3 (main, Apr  2 2022, 13:52:10) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> /Users/ユーザー名/miniforge3/bin/python /Users/ユーザー名/python/bmi
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    /Users/ユーザー名/miniforge3/bin/python /Users/ユーザー名/python/bmi
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

＜追記＞
新しく追加された画像を拝見しましたが、Pythonインタープリターを指定されていませんよ。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。もしかしたらそうかもしれません。特に設定はいじらずにshft+enterを押しているのですが、間違えているのでしょうか。

Comment: Pythonインタープリターが指定されていないとダメなんですね。調べてやってみます。

Comment: endymion様。インタープリターについて調べたのですが、インタープリターの選択肢がたくさん出てきてどれを選べばいいのかわかりませんでした。スクリーンショットを追加しました。よろしければどれが

Comment: あなたの環境では、通常どのpythonを指定していますか？
ターミナルからwhichコマンドなどで確認できます。

% which python

ターミナルでpipやcondaコマンドを実行すると、numpyなどライブラリは指定のpythonにインストールされます。
パッケージがインストールされたpythonを一覧から選んでください。

選び方を間違うと、プログラム実行時にパッケージが見つからず、importエラーになります。

Comment: ターミナルに％　which python と入力したところ、/Users/ユーザー名/miniforge3/bin/pythonと出てきました。これが記載されているインタープリターを選べばいいということでしょうか？

Comment: VSCodeから実行するpythonと、ターミナルから実行するpythonを一致させておけばよいです。